# Extract line that don't repeat

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, uniq

I have a [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) file with duplicate lines and I need to extract only the non repeating lines.

For example, I have

```
12
13
14
12
13
15
```

and the desired output is:

```
14
15
```

Comment: Post sample data and your attempts to solve it.

Comment: @pfnuesel almost had it `sort file | uniq -u`

Answer (score 2):

To find the unique lines in a file you can use `uniq -u` *(required sorted file):*

```
$ sort file | uniq -u    
14
15
```

An alternative method using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(k in a)if(a[k]==1)print k}' file
14
15
```